# iOS 7 - Local Declaration hides instance variable when calling results from a database query

Tags: objective-c

I have this function that takes results from a database query. I am using the FMDB Library to query the database. However, I have a feeling that I am not properly transferring the query results to my mutable array. Here is my fucntion

```
-(NSArray *)initializeGroupIDArray{
    // Getting the database path.
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"itemList.db"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];

    NSString *sqlSelectQuery = @"SELECT DISTINCT GROUPID FROM ItemList";

    // Query result
    FMResultSet *resultsWithNameLocation = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];

    while([resultsWithNameLocation next]) {
        NSString *itemName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[resultsWithNameLocation stringForColumn:@"GROUPID"]];
    
        // loading your data into the array, dictionaries.
        NSLog(@"GroupID = %@", itemName);
        [groupArray addObject:itemName];
    }
    [database close];

    NSArray *groupID;
    [groupID = groupArray copy];

    return groupID;
}
```

A warning comes up at the lines `NSLog(@"GroupID = %@", itemName);` and  `[groupArray addObject:itemName];` at it says that the local declaration of `itemName` hides instance variable. I have a feeling that this is the culprit behind me not being able to properly add the results to my array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the following search results on that error: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+local+declaration+hides+instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of `itemName` in the code you shared looks correct to me. The error message indicates that your class has an instance variable named `itemName`, which would make your usage of `itemName` in the `NSLog` and `addObject:` cases ambiguous (as two variables, one in your local scope, and one in your class scope, would be sharing the same variable name).

Fix this issue by choosing a new unique name for your `NSString *itemName` variable within this method.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this, I had another variable within the class scope that had the same name. I used another name for that function and now it works. Thank you.